# No chimes at start up

Tags: macos, startup

I am using 10.10.3 and need to do command R at the start up chimes but there are not any chimes and never have been, even on earlier versions. I have done a disk verify and it says there are some problems to sort out which I'm hoping will be the answer to some of my applications not opening (just bouncing) I have checked the sound/mute and that's fine and I can play audio no problem. Hopefully someone with more ideas than I can help.

Comment: I've closed your follow on question as a duplicate of this. Could you have a look at [ask] before asking your second question here. Also, note that Basic Customer support is off-topic here. If you have a startup issue, be sure to STFW and link to an Apple support article that you are using to diagnose your issue. That way we can help you along without needing to guess what you've tried already.

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting the PRAM/NVRAM on your computer. Turn off your computer, put your fingers over the <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> keys,  turn on your computer, and **before the screen lights up**, start holding down those four keys. Hold them down until you hear the startup chime a second time. Good luck!